# Mixpanel conflicts with async/await functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, mixpanel

Below is the sample html page with async/await function it works as expected but if we add Mixpanel default code async section fails.

**Mixpanel default code**

```
<!-- start Mixpanel --><script type="text/javascript">

(function(c,a){if(!a.__SV){var b=window;try{var d,m,j,k=b.location,f=k.hash;d=function(a,b){return(m=a.match(RegExp(b+"=([^&]*)")))?m[1]:null};f&&d(f,"state")&&(j=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(d(f,"state"))),"mpeditor"===j.action&&(b.sessionStorage.setItem("_mpcehash",f),history.replaceState(j.desiredHash||"",c.title,k.pathname+k.search)))}catch(n){}var l,h;window.mixpanel=a;a._i=[];a.init=function(b,d,g){function c(b,i){var a=i.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],i=a[1]);b[i]=function(){b.push([i].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,
0)))}}var e=a;"undefined"!==typeof g?e=a[g]=[]:g="mixpanel";e.people=e.people||[];e.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==g&&(a+="."+g);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};e.people.toString=function(){return e.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};l="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split(" ");
for(h=0;h<l.length;h++)c(e,l[h]);var f="set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" ");e.get_group=function(){function a(c){b[c]=function(){call2_args=arguments;call2=[c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args,0));e.push([d,call2])}}for(var b={},d=["get_group"].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)),c=0;c<f.length;c++)a(f[c]);return b};a._i.push([b,d,g])};a.__SV=1.2;b=c.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?
MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===c.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";d=c.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("MIXPANEL_ID", {loaded: function() {
       let distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
});

</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->
```

***Sample Html code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->


</head>
<body>
  <strong> Hope you are able to get 3 alerts. If no then please remove Mixpanel default code</strong>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = async function () {

      await  loadResponse(" without await");
   }
   console.log("Start")
  async function loadResponse(msg) {
           console.log("Load Response"+msg)
       }
    console.log(" before await")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-js/blob/f9314b63d0c6de26b6d515a756eafc08c95c9975/doc/readme.io/javascript-full-api-reference.md#mixpanelget_distinct_id

**There are two minor changes that has to be done in mixpanel default code**

```
1> let distinct_id = false;
2> mixpanel.init("MIXPANEL_ID", {loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
}
```

**Another changes has to be done in onload function**

```
  
1> setTimeout(
```

**Updated code with mixpanel**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<!-- start Mixpanel --><script type="text/javascript">
let distinct_id = false;
(function(c,a){if(!a.__SV){var b=window;try{var d,m,j,k=b.location,f=k.hash;d=function(a,b){return(m=a.match(RegExp(b+"=([^&]*)")))?m[1]:null};f&&d(f,"state")&&(j=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(d(f,"state"))),"mpeditor"===j.action&&(b.sessionStorage.setItem("_mpcehash",f),history.replaceState(j.desiredHash||"",c.title,k.pathname+k.search)))}catch(n){}var l,h;window.mixpanel=a;a._i=[];a.init=function(b,d,g){function c(b,i){var a=i.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],i=a[1]);b[i]=function(){b.push([i].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,
0)))}}var e=a;"undefined"!==typeof g?e=a[g]=[]:g="mixpanel";e.people=e.people||[];e.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==g&&(a+="."+g);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};e.people.toString=function(){return e.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};l="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split(" ");
for(h=0;h<l.length;h++)c(e,l[h]);var f="set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" ");e.get_group=function(){function a(c){b[c]=function(){call2_args=arguments;call2=[c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args,0));e.push([d,call2])}}for(var b={},d=["get_group"].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)),c=0;c<f.length;c++)a(f[c]);return b};a._i.push([b,d,g])};a.__SV=1.2;b=c.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?
MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===c.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";d=c.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("MIXPANEL_ID", {loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
});

</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->


</head>
<body>
  <strong> Hope you are able to get 3 alerts. If no then please remove Mixpanel default code</strong>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(
  window.onload = async function () {

      await  loadResponse(" without await");
   }, 300)
   console.log("Start")
  async function loadResponse(msg) {
           console.log("Load Response"+msg)
       }
    console.log(" before await")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please do let me know if you have any other solution.